# Как сохранить данные из ArrayAdapter`a в БД?

Tags: android

В главном активити вводится строка и добавляется в список ListView:

```
mValue1 = edt.getText().toString();


                stroki.add(new StrokiInfo(mValue1, statustest));
                TopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Вот так выглядит адаптер:

```
public class TopAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StrokiInfo> {


ArrayList<StrokiInfo> stroki = new ArrayList<StrokiInfo>();
//delete mb ^^


public TopAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<StrokiInfo> stroki) {
    super(context, 0, strimi);
    this.stroki = stroki;


}

public ArrayList<StrokiInfo> getItems() {
    return stroki;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return stroki.size();
}

@Override
public StrokiInfo getItem(int position) {
    return stroki.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    StrokiInfo data = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }

    TextView column1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.col1);
    TextView column2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.col2);


    column1.setText(data.par1);
    column2.setText(data.par2);


    return convertView;
}
```

После выхода из приложения, все строки списка теряются. Как получить данные из адаптера, чтобы сохранить их в БД, для дальнейшего считывания из БД и вывода списка на экран при новом запуске приложения?
P.S. в адаптере методы get не получилось реализовать, но здесь их специально не удалил.

Comment: есть 2 способа - простой и правильный. Правильный - сначала сохранять данные в БД, а потом - использовать `CursorAdapter`. Простой - сохранить данные из адаптера, используя `getCount()`, `getItem()`

Comment: "Правильный" способ предполагает использовать другой адаптер, а мне нужно оставить ArrayAdapter.. Подскажите, как реализовать в нём getCount и getItem

Comment: Зачем еще нужно оставить `ArrayAdapter`, если он не подходит для решаемой задачи? Гонять данные из базы в список и обратно - бесполезная работа, только потери ресурсов.

Answer (score 3):

Реализовывать сохранение куда-то каких-то данных в адаптере плохая идея. Необходимо сначала сохранить данные, а потом добавлять их в адаптер.

Код может выглядеть так:

```
mValue1 = edt.getText().toString();
StrokiInfo info = new StrokiInfo(mValue1, statustest);
saveData(info); // сохраняем данные туда, куда нужно
stroki.add(info);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Соответственно, при создании адаптера необходимо данные загрузить и передать в адаптер:

```
List<StrokiInfo> list = loadData(); // загружаем данные 
TopAdapter adapter = new TopAdapter(context,list);
```

Comment: хм, так и вправду выглядит правильнее. Сейчас попробую..

Comment: только не `TopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, а `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @miha_dev я так думаю что у автора так названа переменная адаптера в классе активити, но на всякий случай подправлю, спасибо.